# Automate CosmosDB emulator setup

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I would like to create scripts to prepare dev CosmosDB emulator with all the databases, containers and index policies. Is there a way to do this?

I saw there is some PowerShell commandlets, but those are just for administrative tasks only. Cosmos Db CLI  doesn't seem to have any of needed capabilities as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is great PowerShell module [CosmosDB](https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB#create-a-context-for-a-cosmos-db-emulator) which can help in many ways automating emulator. The only struggle and challenge for me would be to have some kind of automatic transition from Terraform scripts (container names, db setup, indexes and etc) to PowerShell.